# react-scripts 5.0.0 bringing in extra webpack dependency

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have an existing project updating to `react-scripts@5.0.0`. Trying to build or run the dev server is resulting in

```
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
```

Following recommendations that this is due to conflicting webpack versions I found the following in my `node_modules`.

```
node_modules/webpack
node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/.bin/webpack <--- the culprit
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
```

If I generate a fresh project using CRA all works find and node_modules looks like this

```
node_modules/webpack
node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack
```

Deleting the extra webpack under `node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/` makes my project start working but running an npm install causes it to come back.

Where could this be coming from? Why does my project bring this in but a fresh CRA project does not?

**Update 1**

I should mention that adding overrides to my package.json didn't help.

```
"overrides": {
    "webpack": "5.70.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the corresponding `react-scripts/node_modules/webpack` entries from `package-lock.json` cleared this up.